# Best Public cyrptocurrency APIs to develop exchange

Tags: blockchain, exchanges, api

We are developing cyrptocurrency API where we are relying on Blockcypher for several currencies. But we would like to add more and more currencies to our exchange. But it seems all crypto currencies look to develop our own node and make rpc request to that from localhost itself.

We are looking free REST api to generate addresses and make transactions.

Is there any source or idea from where we can get the API of most of the currencies.